# how to completely turn off caching on iis7

Tags: javascript, caching, iis-7

I have an asp.net MVC application that has a lot of .js and .css files.  However, when I make an update the output caching (or at least that is what I think it is) prevents my sites from getting updated.

I have tried to turn it off through the IIS7 UI as well through the applicationHost.config file.  However, to no avail, it takes hours (sometimes a day or more) before my IIS7 server starts serving the new / updated files.

I have read lots of posts on this but I am missing something here.  For now, I would be happy to completely disable all caching on my IIS7 server as it's still in development.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of turning off caching you might consider using `System.Web.Optimization` and `Bundle`s. This appends a hash to the bundle URL that automatically gets updated when the dependant files change.